# reading a tab delimited text file line by line get data after <tab> in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

My data looks like this:

```
8/29/2013<tab>1<tab>name<tab>aaaaaaaaaaa<tab>12
8/29/2013<tab>22<tab>asd<tab>asd<tab>123
8/29/2013<tab>23<tab>xycabc<tab>asd<tab>12
```

and i need something like this:

```
RECEIVED on:8/29/2013 FROM:name AMOUNT:12
RECEIVED on:8/29/2013 FROM:asdAMOUNT:123
```

I've tried this:

```
Dim rvsr As New IO.StreamReader(vcFile)
Dim vText As String
Dim vstring(-1) As String
p1 = "    "
Dim vData As String = ""
While rvsr.Peek <> -1
    vText = rvsr.ReadLine()
    vstring = vText.Split(p1)
    vData = vData + vbCrLf + "RECEIVED ON: " + vstring(0) + " FROM: " + vstring(1) + " AMOUNT: " + vstring(2)
End While
RichTextBox_WD.Text = vData
rvsr.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Without showing us what you are getting I can not be sure what exactly is happening. But in looking at your code I believe the problem has to do with how you are using your Split. I have modified your code to fit in a console application using the [`vbTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtab.aspx) Constant and the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) Method that uses string seperators, see if this is what you are wanting.

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim vText As String
        Dim vstring(-1) As String
        Dim p1 As String() = {vbTab} 'Note I am using a string array and the vbTab Constant
        Dim vData As String = ""
        Using rvsr As New StreamReader("C:\\temp\\source.txt")
            While rvsr.Peek <> -1
                vText = rvsr.ReadLine()
                vstring = vText.Split(p1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'I am also using the option to remove empty entries a
                vData = vData + vbCrLf + "Recieved On:" + vstring(0) + " From:" + vstring(2) + " Amount:" + vstring(4)

            End While
        End Using
        Console.Write(vData)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RichTextBox_WD.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, File.ReadLines(vcFile).Select(Function(line)
                                                                            Dim format = "RECEIVED ON: {0} FROM: {1} AMOUNT {2}"
                                                                            Dim fields = line.Split(vbTab)
                                                                            Return String.Format(format, fields(0), fields(1), fields(2))
                                                                        End Function)
```

I prefer to create a `Joined` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` which wraps `String.Join` (taking a delimiter and an optional transformation delegate), and a `Formatted` extension method on `String` which wraps `String.Format`:

```
RichTextBox_WD.Text = File.ReadLines(vcFile).Joined(vbCrLf, Function(line)
                                                                Dim format = "RECEIVED ON: {0} FROM: {1} AMOUNT {2}"
                                                                Dim fields = lines.Split(VbTab)
                                                                Return format.Formmatted(fields(0), fields(1), fields(2))
                                                            End Function)
```